# PSQL: "Error: column x does not exist"

Tags: sql, postgresql

I successfully created a database with a schema.sql file:

```
CREATE DATABASE movie_db;

\c movie_db

DROP TABLE movies;

CREATE TABLE movies (
  id BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  title VARCHAR(255),
  year integer,
  description VARCHAR(255),
  posterUrl VARCHAR(255),
  screenshotUrl VARCHAR(255)
);
```

But when I attempt to connect the seed.sql file it's telling me that `ERROR: column "After the death of his father, T'Challa returns home to..." does not exist` :

```
\c movie_db

INSERT INTO movies (title, year, description, posterUrl, screenshotUrl)
VALUES ('Black Panther', 2018, "After the death of his father, T'Challa returns home to...", 'https://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMTg1MTY2MjYzNV5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwMTc4NTMwNDI@._V1_UX182_CR0,0,182,268_AL_.jpg', 'http://cdn.wegotthiscovered.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/black-panther-movie-image-9.jpg');
```

There was another movie that I was able to successfully insert into the db that's structurally identical to the Black Panther info.

At first I thought there was a problem with the ' in T'Challa, but when I removed it I still couldn't connect. It's probably something pretty obvious, but it's been bugging me so I thought I'd ask the audience.

Comment: Use single quotes for string literals! (Double quotes are for delimited identifiers, e.g. column names.)

Comment: `INSERT INTO movies (title, year, description, posterUrl, screenshotUrl)
VALUES ('Black Panther', 2018, $$After the death of his father, T'Challa returns home to...$$, 'https://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMTg1MTY2MjYzNV5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwMTc4NTMwNDI@._V1_UX182_CR0,0,182,268_AL_.jpg', 'http://cdn.wegotthiscovered.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/black-panther-movie-image-9.jpg');`

Comment: also - does ANY question automatically get upvoted?..

Comment: @VaoTsun, I use to ask myself the same question...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%E2%80%9CError%3A+column+x+does+not+exist%E2%80%9D gives 870 results! and first few are exact match

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-CONSTANTS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try phrasing this with single quotes:

```
INSERT INTO movies (title, year, description, posterUrl, screenshotUrl)
    VALUES ('Black Panther', 2018, 'After the death of his father, T''Challa returns home to...', 'https://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMTg1MTY2MjYzNV5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwMTc4NTMwNDI@._V1_UX182_CR0,0,182,268_AL_.jpg', 'http://cdn.wegotthiscovered.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/black-panther-movie-image-9.jpg');
```

To escape a single quote in SQL, use two single quotes in a row.